# Autofac AggregateService exists in NuGet?

Tags: nuget, autofac

I found Autofac [AggregateService](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AggregateService) awesome but what is the right way to include it in my project: clone it from [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/checkout) or use NuGet?

I got used to use NuGet but I can't find nothing about AggegateService there. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that AggregateService and the other Extras are currently "in limbo". There's been a recent change in that the contributions are now being made part of the same solution as Autofac core, while they were previously a separate solution. From [the current build file](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/default.proj) you can see that extras will be made available as a separate Autofac.Extras package and a separate download from the Autofac page.

Meanwhile, you can use [AutofacContrib 2.6.1](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/downloads/detail?name=AutofacContrib-2.6.1.841-NET40.zip&can=2&q=) or to grab the source and compile a dll yourself.

Btw, thanks for finding AggregateService awesome ;)

**Update**: actually, reading the build file properly (and looking at the current source structure), the Extras parts will be distributed as individual packages. So expect to find Autofac.Extras.AggregateService on Nuget in the future.

Comment: The update is correct - the Extras are planned to be distributed as individual packages on NuGet once we get things settled out for Autofac 3.0. There was previously inconsistent handling of Extras distribution on NuGet and one of the key goals of the next major version is to address that shortcoming.